# True or false if $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers$b_n$ converges to 0, then $a_n\over b_n$ diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

True or false: 
if $a_n$ is any decreasing sequence of positive real numbers and $b_n$ is any sequence of real numbers converges to 0, then $a_n\over b_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $a_n=e^{-n} $ and $b_n=\frac {1}{n^2} $ then

$(a_n) $ is a decreasing sequence of positive numbers and $\lim_{+\infty}b_n=0$

but

$$\frac {a_n}{b_n}=n^2e^{-n}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Take $a_n=b_n=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: ya, that's what I did, but I wasn't sure if it was correct. A sequence of decreasing positive numbers should converge to zero. thanks

Comment: @Jasmine "*A sequence of decreasing positive numbers should converge to zero*"... that statement is not at all true.  $c_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers which converges to $1$ instead.  It just so happens that the example tattwamasi gives converges to zero in this specific case.

Comment: @Jasmine:  A sequence of decreasing positive numbers need not converge to zero.  $c_n=1+\frac 1n$ is decreasing and positive but converges to $1$.  This example meets your requirements on $a_n,b_n$ and it is constant so it converges.

Comment: thanx for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$